# Will disabling the Form Builder UI do anything to my webforms?

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to disable the form builder UI so that I can select "multiple option" for a select list in the default webforms editor. This feature is missing in form builder. Can I do this or will it clear out all the work I've done building the forms within the form builder UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Form builder](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder) is just a user interface. It does nothing to the forms themselves. The display and use of the forms is dependent upon the modules that implement the forms. so, yes, you can disable it with no effect on your existing forms.