# Webform select list multiple selection

Tags: webforms

I've added a webform component of type Select list. How do I configure the select list to let users select multiple options?

Thank for reply to let me know there is a check box call multiple, but I have no idea where is it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the edit screen for your select list component (`node/NODE_ID/webform/components/COMPONENT_ID`), there's a checkbox labeled "Multiple" whose description says "Check this option if the user should be allowed to choose multiple values."

With that checkbox checked, by default your component will be displayed as a set of checkboxes. To get it to display instead as a select element, look further down on the edit screen for the component, under the "Display" section. There's a checkbox labeled "Listbox" whose description says "Check this option if you want the select component to be displayed as a select list box instead of radio buttons or checkboxes."

EDIT: here's a screenshot of Webform's select component interface when used with the Bartik theme:
[image]

EDIT 2:
After googling "drupal form builder select multiple", I found [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1693504) which suggests that via form builder's UI you need to use the "checkboxes" component type in order to have a "select multiple" field. Per [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73896/will-disabling-the-form-builder-ui-do-anything-to-my-webforms) you could disable form builder's UI and then you'll get the stock webform UI where you'll find the checkbox.

Comment: I cant find the checkbox.

Comment: Are you using an additional module that modifies the behavior of Webform. Perhaps something like Options Element (https://www.drupal.org/project/options_element)? I see in your screenshot that you haven't entered any select options yet. Maybe such a module is hiding the "multiple" checkbox until you have some options entered?

Comment: I never download options_element. I purposely remove the list of option because it is very long. Anyway, I do install form builder. Does that affect? Can you show me the picture?

Comment: I've never used form builder but I suspect that's what's affecting Webform's behavior. I'll add a screenshot of what Webform's stock interface looks like when editing a select component.

Comment: The problem is i cant disable form building. If I disable form builder, I cant acccess Form components. I struck with this form builder.

Comment: It's worth testing to see if you disable form builder, use webform's interface to change the "multiple" setting, and then reenable form builder, maybe the setting will stick. In any case, disabling form builder doesn't prevent you from accessing the form components, you'd just access them with webform's interface instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like webform_select_options_info, or The [webform views sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mrconnerton/1373760), or you can modify the approach here in your own module [Sample Request](http://drupalsteve.com/node/57)

This approach means writing a little custom module. Webform_select_options_info() basically just takes an array of what ever you want them to be able to select multiple options of. the Approach in the second link uses a view for formatting, but you can spin off to your needs there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox on the select list edit form that enables multiple selection.

[image]

Comment: I cant find the checkbox.

Comment: Based on your theme, I'd presume it would be under the `Properties` tab. On the themes I used webform on, I don't have fieldsets being rendered as tabs.

Comment: As you can see the picture above. Properties does not have checkbox. Only title and description.
FYI, first picture is properties tab. Second picture is display tab. Third picture is Options tab and Last picture is Validation tab. All the them do not have any checkbox for Multiple